# javascript: how can I know what functions available in current context?

Tags: javascript, html

In a web page, it may import external javascript files, and it may contains inline javascript code, it may also use a activex control which may also expose javascript api, then how can I know all the functions available there in a web page?

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the `window` object and filter the functions:

```
function getFunctions(obj)
{
    var functions = {};
    for (var attr in obj)
    {
        if ( typeof(obj[attr])=="function" )
        {
                functions[attr] = obj[attr];
        }
    }
    return functions;
}

var functions = getFunctions(window);
```